# How to convert a String to a Float with Swift 2.0?

Tags: string, swift

I am trying to convert a string I load from an xml file  to a float so i can set a slider value to 86.

When I use this code, it prints 0.0 ? but it has to be 86 !

Does somebody know why and how I can fix this ?

```
    var strXMLData:String = ""
    var currentElement:String = ""
    var passData:Bool=false
    var passName:Bool=false
    var parser = NSXMLParser()
    var string = ""

     let urlToSend: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
            // Parse the XML
            parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: urlToSend)!
            parser.delegate = self

            let success:Bool = parser.parse()

            if success {
                print("parse success!")

                print(strXMLData)

                string = strXMLData

                var float = (string as NSString).floatValue
                VolumeSlider.setValue(float)
                print(float)



            } else {
                print("parse failure!")
            }




            if(WCSession.isSupported()){
                self.session = WCSession.defaultSession()
                self.session.delegate = self
                self.session.activateSession()

    }
    }




    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
        currentElement=elementName;
        if(elementName=="e2current")
        {
            if(elementName=="e2current"){
                passName=true;

            }
            passData=true;
        }

    }
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        currentElement="";
        if(elementName=="e2current")
        {
            if(elementName=="e2current"){
                passName=false;
            }
            passData=false;
        }

    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        if(passName){
            strXMLData=strXMLData+"\n\n"+string
        }

        if(passData)
        {
            print(string)
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
        NSLog("failure error: %@", parseError)
    }
```

Comment: @coder1000 where did you go ?

Comment: I am here. No worries. Sadly, I don't see what's the issue yet :/

Comment: well oke, if you get a idea let me know ;) !

Comment: Of Course  ! I will. :)

Comment: I am confused with what you are actually trying to do. You get a URL response, and need to parse out a string value that represents a float value? So the string would say "86.0"?

Comment: What exactly does `strXMLData` print? Are there spaces? Or maybe a plus sign?

Comment: strXmlData prints a string: this is the xml file` <e2volume>
<e2result>True</e2result>
<e2resulttext>Status</e2resulttext>
<e2current>71</e2current>
<e2ismuted>False</e2ismuted>
</e2volume>`

Comment: @QuinnDonkers Well, but that's what you are trying to convert to a float. That's definitely not a number...

Comment: You should name your variables something else than their type. Something descriptive but not use system reserved words, such as float(Float), string(String). That could potentially make trouble for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working guys !

I had to change the value when I received it in the `viewDidLoad` but in the `func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {`

thank you guys but i got it working know.

```
 func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    if(passName){
        strXMLData=strXMLData+"\n\n"+string
    }

    if(passData)
    {
        print(string)

        let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
        let theNumber = numberFormatter.numberFromString(string)
        let floatValue = Float(theNumber!)

        print(floatValue)

        VolumeSlider.setValue(floatValue)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used this solution earlier. Don't know why your code didn't work, but at least this get's the job done...only with several lines of code.

```
var textNumber = "123456.789"
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
let theNumber = numberFormatter.numberFromString(textNumber)
var floatValue = Double(theNumber!) //123456.789
```

Comment: Are you sure that the number your are receiving are not 0.0?

Comment: it is a good code, when you use it how you do. but keep in mind i have to go from string to float from the received string of the xml file

Comment: I use this to receive a number stored as a String. Then I use this code to convert it to a number. Do you know what value your received xml is?

Answer (score 1):

After going through your parsing code, we can basically simplify it into the following:

Set `passData` to `true` when we are inside the element:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    if (elementName == "e2current")  {
        passData = true;
    }
}
```

Set `passData` to `false` when we are not inside the element:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if (elementName == "e2current") {
        passData = false;
    }
}
```

Save the value when we are inside the element

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    if (passData){
        strXMLData = string
    }
}
```

Note that when you start adding `\n\n` to the string, you won't be able to parse that value.

A more sensible implementation would probably be:

```
var elementStack: [String] = []

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    elementStack.append(elementName)
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    elementStack.removeLast()
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    if (elementStack.last == "e2current") {
        strXMLData = string
    }
}
```